# Is it OK to edit obvious spam to break links?

Tags: discussion, spam

I know moderators tend to handle spam flags pretty quickly, so this may not be entirely necessary, but I was wondering if it would be counter productive to break the links in obvious spam posts.

I'm thinking that the majority of spam is trying to drive traffic to a site, if even well meaning users click on the spam's link out of morbid curiosity the spam has done its job.

Breaking the link without changing the overall content of the post could diminish the effect of the spam without disguising its [spamminess](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spamminess).

For example, change:

> Hey checkout our suspiciously overpriced and potentially malicious
>   product at http://example.com

To:

> Hey checkout our suspiciously overpriced and potentially malicious
>   product at h-ttp://example.com

The only downside would be that the edit would bump the post...

Should I just leave it alone or would this sort of edit be acceptable?

Comment: Related: [Should Spam posts be edited?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited) - consensus is no, you shouldn't edit it.

Comment: @hichris123 I thought about that, that was why I suggested breaking the link rather than hiding the content all together.

Comment: Is it ok? I don't see what it hurts. Is it worth the trouble? I would say not unless you see one that the mods hadn't gotten to quickly enough. If you want to be safe then you could always add a comment deterring users from following the link.

Comment: Spam with edit history takes me an order of magnitude longer to validate.

Comment: great question...  might not have thought about this otherwise.

Comment: From [this related question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327636/educating-people-to-flag-spam-and-not-vote-to-close?noredirect=1&lq=1) 6 spam flags delete the post, so don't edit, flag it.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The best way to make spam ineffective **is to delete it quickly!** The single best thing you can do when you see spam is flag it:

[image: I am flagging this question because it is spam]

Just about *anything* else you can do is at *best* a waste of your time and effort, unless it somehow leads directly to more folks flagging the post as spam. Editing in particular can actually be counter-productive, both by making the spam less obvious to other flaggers and by [allowing folks to roll back flags added since the edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work).

Thinking you're gonna discourage *future* spam by breaking the links is, I'm afraid, rather naive; best we can tell, most spam is *very nearly free* to whoever is behind it - indeed, a tremendous amount is blocked automatically and never seen by *anyone*, much less followed... Yet the cost to generate it is apparently so low that this doesn't matter, meaning *any* extra time you spend on it is time wasted.

#### See also: [Should Spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited)

Comment: Perhaps the system could be updated to automatically "break" links in posts flagged as spam (and perhaps display a notice to that effect) until the moderators have a chance to address it. This accomplishes @apaul34208's goal of reducing traffic to spam sites a bit more quickly without reducing the effectiveness of the moderation system.

Comment: @LarsKemmann rather than break it I would suggest a pop up saying `Warning, this post was flagged as spam. Do you wish to proceed? [Y/N]`

Comment: @AdmiralAdama You should put that as a feature request :) Although some spam is done to drive up their search engine rankings by making their site look more reputable (because a big site like StackOverflow is linking to it) so it wouldn't help in that case.

Comment: I think the idea of the popup from @AdmiralAdama is great... would also encourage the clicker to think about flagging  (well, would actually bias them to do so, but this might be desirable if we are biased against spam)