# Create a warning when clicking potential spam links

Tags: feature-request, spam

There was a popular question about what to do with spam links yesterday. [The post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263051/is-it-ok-to-edit-obvious-spam-to-break-links) was asking if an editor should 'break' the link to prevent people from clicking it on accident or without thinking.

The popular response was just to flag it and ignore it. Anything else was considered to be a bit of a waste and even detrimental to the cause. Of course in-between the spam flags and action being taken, the link is still just as clickable.

I proposed that if a post is flagged as spam ***x*** number times, then any link in that post should create some sort of warning asking for user confirmation before proceeding.

A pop up that says: `Warning, this post was flagged as spam. Do you wish to proceed? [Y/N]`

It could also be something as simple as a little annotation that is red and says `Click the link but be warned this has been flagged as spam.` *(This might be more in line with current features...)*

It shouldn't be too intrusive to users, and should only help protect the user who is absently mindedly browsing some stack exchange site. It would also encourage the use of appropriate flags for the appropriate instance.

Comment: AFAIK if a post was flagged as spam X times, it is automatically deleted (with no specific disclosure about the value of X).

Comment: @l4mpi From [What are the spam and offensive flags, and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work): *6 flags (spam or offensive): post is locked, deleted, and the first revision owner loses 100 reputation.*

Comment: From the posts I have seen yes, after 6 flags the post is deleted. I think the original question asker was just hoping for another safeguard mechanism. I am sure it would not bring a ton of value to the community, but it may help a little and it may even help someone avoid a malicious spam post.

Comment: Meh. In this day and age anyone who will blindly click a link offered on a site that consists of user-provided content is more than welcome to click the link to my bridge-for-sale Pinterest page.

Answer (score 8):

This is already done, to a degree. When a post is flagged as spam and later deleted (through flags or deletion votes), the content of the entire post is automatically hidden behind the following:

[image]

to anyone (10k+) who can view deleted posts.

If you click through all that to view the post, and still click on the link, you know what you're getting into.