# Someone just edited nonsense/spam links into other nonsense/spam links; isn't this inappropriate?

Tags: discussion, spam, specific-edit, review-abuse

Someone just edited [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76751374/2057969) (which I flagged as "abusive", since it was mostly a gibberish "test post") containing two links to a similar looking gibberish test blog.

The original (excerpt):

> qưheiuqwhtext
> ...
> Now that you’re ready to post your question, read through it from start to finish. Does it make sense?
> ...
> `<some link to a gibberish test blog>`

with "text" also in blue, linking to the same gibberish test blog. A high-rep user then came along and replaced both of these (identical) links by links to `http://spam2407.spamblog.com/`.

This strikes me as an entirely pointless edit. Also it seems that that user doesn't need it to meet some badge threshold (for the "Copy Editor" badge or some such). I am perplexed. Is such behavior acceptable, or should we do something about it? If so, what?

What some people do is to flag as spam/abusive (whichever applies) and post a comment along the lines of "I am flagging this as XYZ because ...", but the editor in question didn't do this. (Therefore I couldn't "at" (`@`) that user in a comment explaining my concerns.)

Comment: There's a canonical post about this on MSE: [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/241919). I believe the editor did it in good faith, though it's somewhat counter-productive.

Comment: @AndrewT. Should I delete this question on SO Meta or keep it here?

Comment: Looks like it's a duplicate, but it's up to you to keep it here or delete it though :)

Comment: @AndrewT. Got it. Lemme keep it here if that's okay. There is one question that I consider unsolved: Shouldn't we communicate this (that we shouldn't edit spam posts) to the editor in question? If so, how?

Comment: Also related/possible dupe: [Is it OK to edit obvious spam to break links?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263051/2821954) in case the current dupe doesn't really fit.

Comment: Re: communicating, [users can actually ping the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333010/241919), it just doesn't autocomplete.

Comment: @AndrewT. This is valuable information, and I didn't know this. I guess you could post this as an answer? Either way, I'll leave this question for the purpose of indexing, as it's (slightly) different from the existing ones.

Comment: Normally, most spam & abusive posts get rapidly dealt with by the [Charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) team and their trusty Smoke Detector bot. But they're currently [on strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811), and many regular users aren't aware of the proper procedures required for dealing with spam.

Comment: @PM2Ring now I'm starting to doubt myself. Its to flag the post as spam right? Nothing else? When you call it a procedure it starts to sound like its a whole checklist.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, just flag it. And the system will automatically delete it when it accumulates enough flags (normally on SO that's 6, but it's currently reduced to 4, due to the strike action).

Comment: However, many people do other stuff instead: downvote, close-vote, write angry or sarcastic comments, etc.